# Error submitting Monotouch application - "Unable to locate the metadata-template.xml file within the application"

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm trying to submit an iPhone application developed in MonoTouch and I'm getting the cryptic error "Unable to locate the metadata-template.xml file within the application".

I'm using the Application Loader and the application runs fine on the simulator and an iPhone.

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.  I don't even know where to start looking...

Answer (score 0):

Is this a file that you deleted from your project, but is still referenced somewhere in a config or metadata file?

Comment: That's a good guess.  The structure did change a little bit, but I'm pretty sure I never added any files with that name, and I don't see anything.  I looked in the .csproj file and all of the settings.  Is there anywhere else you can think of for me to look?

Comment: No, but I would try grepping through the entire project tree, including the bin folder and app bundles.

Answer (score 0):

I received this problem and believe it was cause by my incorrectly saving over an Info.plist file in a framework in my post-build script.  After fixing this, I needed to quit Application Loader and resubmit the app for it to go through.