# Uploading the app failed, on iTunes for app store. ***-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] nil arguments**

Tags: ios, objective-c, submit, application-loader

I am submitting my app to iTunes for review but every time I tried to upload I am receiving the error
***-[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] nil arguments**
[image]

I have checked every thing but couldn't find its meaning that what is missing.
I am using Xcode5 with IOS7.0

All the app icons and launch images are included but same error appears each time.

I tried to upload using application loader instead of Xcode by archive but same error appears.
[image]

If anyone knows about it kindly help me. I have to submit it as soon as possible.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `purple-metadata-template.xml` file in your application?

Comment: There is mention of this file in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352018/error-submitting-monotouch-application-unable-to-locate-the-metadata-template) question, try having a look at that?

Comment: @Rich, No I do not have any xml file in my project, even I don't know where it exists in the project.

Comment: Are you using monotouch?

Comment: NO, I am using standard objective-c and Xcode

Comment: Have you go anything weird in your `Info.plist` file?

Comment: Now I am uploading another app on iTunes, which is entirely different from the other in which I faced above mentioned error, and this time I am again having the same problem, same error as previous.

Comment: I'd try removing and reinstalling xcode or try a different machine. This looks now to no be an app issue!

Comment: I have uploaded screenshot of info.plist file, I didn't find anything weird in it.

Comment: see my previous comment :)

Comment: I uploaded the app successfully using another macbook having Xcode 4.6

Comment: I am facing this issue. ios Deployment target is 6.0 and i am trying in xcode 5.1.1. The above error is coming..... Its getting into my nerves.... Any clue would help us.

Comment: Its resolved when I have tried in different MAC